# How can I manipulate this text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

The Xpath is

```
 //*[@id="main-results"]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text()
```

The actual HTML is

```
 <div class="medium-item-price"><span class="denominator">$</span>699.99</div>
```

I want to change 699.99 to another number.

```
$(document).getElementByClassName("medium-item-price").Value = 100;
```

Comment: try `$(document).getElementsByClassName("medium-item-price")[0].textContent`

Comment: try `$('#main-results .medium-item-price').first().text('$100')` i cant tell from your xpath if the `first()` will target the right node though.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be sufficient? Just notice this will remove `.denominator`, and replace the inner text with desired value.

```
$('.medium-item-price').text('$1')
```

```js
$('.medium-item-price').text('$1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-item-price"><span class="denominator">$</span>699.99</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('.medium-item-price').contents().last()[0].textContent='100';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-item-price">
  <span class="denominator">$</span>
  699.99
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stLg13h0/

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("medium-item-price")[0].innerText);

document.getElementsByClassName("medium-item-price")[0].innerText = 700;
```

```html
<div class="medium-item-price"><span class="denominator">$</span>699.99</div>
```